# Is there a Twitter Wordpress plugin that changes https to http?

Tags: twitter, https

I log in and do all the administration over https in my wordpress blog (my own installation). When I publish something, I have the problem that the twitter plugins normally pick the current URL, with https:// instead of http:// (I'm currently using WP->Twitter).

When accessed over https:// my page issues some warning and the disqus comments don't work. I really don't care because I should be the only one using https for my blog, but due to the twitter plug in, everybody sees it broken.

Is there some other plug in that solves that? Or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the publish-action in your twitter plugin is your problem. You probably have a twitter widget or something similar, which will display your twitter posts/status on your blog page.

Twitter access his API with a javascript library. Look in your sourcecode. In the HTML HEAD Element, you should see a call to the twitter platform url:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=&#038;v=1&#038;ver=1'></script>
```

This call from your site to the twitter api isn't encrypted. Your browser will show you a message, which will tell that your content is only partial encrypted. The SSL lock isn't displayed.

I've tried to call the platform.twitter.com url over HTTPS. But the certificate is only valid for twiter.com.

Answer (score 0):

The STC-Publish part of [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/) will publish your links correctly. However, STC is a bit more involved of a plugin system, so it does require a bit more setup and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could just fix this in your .htaccess file. This StackOverflow answer is for an Apache server:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess

The best answer has this snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```